# Add link to image when echoing in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, post

In my post form, I have a "show"-page, where I echo out everything in the database. I'm trying to add a link to the image-line. But when I refresh the page, it's just white.

```
<?php
    $sql_connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "root");

    mysql_select_db("database_name", $sql_connection);

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM content ORDER BY id DESC");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<div>";
        echo "<a href="http://www.link.com"><img src=\"http://placehold.it/80x80\"></a> ";
        echo "<br />";
        echo "<br />";
        echo "<h3>" . $row["who"] . "</h3><br />";
        echo "<h4>" . $row["what"] . "</h4><br />";
        echo "<h4>" . $row["where"] . "</h4><br />";
        echo "<h3>" . $row["contact"] . "</h3><br />";
        echo "<img src=\"../img/share_facebook.png\"> ";
        echo "</div>";
    }
    mysql_close($sql_connection);
?>
```

Someone who can explain why this happens?

Comment: basic php syntax: if you're using a `"`-quoted string, you cannot have unescaped `"` **INSIDE** the string - just as in any OTHER language.

Answer (score 3):

```
echo "<a href="http://www.link.com"><img src=\"http://placehold.it/80x80\"></a> ";
```

you have to escape() ALL your " or change to:

```
echo '<a href="http://www.link.com"><img src="http://placehold.it/80x80"></a>';
```

Comment: or better yet, skip repeated echoes and just use a [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc)